# Why is the following equation true?

Tags: number-theory, functions, proof-explanation, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms

This is a fairly simple question but it seems really confusing for me. So basically I am reading the proof of the composition formula of Hecke operators:
$$T(m)T(n)=\sum_{d\mid (m,n)}d^{k-1}T(mn/d^2)$$
The proof is similar to what we did about $\tau(m)\tau(n)$. We just need to prove that
$$T(p^{r+1})=T(p)T(p^r)-p^{k-1}T(p^{r-1})\text{ or }T(p)T(p^r)=T(p^{r+1})+p^{k-1}T(p^{r-1})$$
It is shown that
$$\begin{align*}
    (T(p^{r})f)(\tau)
    &=p^{rk-r}\sum_{j=0}^r p^{-jk}\sum_{b=0}^{p^j-1}f\left(\frac{p^r\tau+bp^j}{p^{2j}}\right)\\
    &=p^{-r}\sum_{\substack{0\leqslant j\leqslant r\\ 0\leqslant b_j<p^j}}p^{(r-j)k}f\left(\frac{p^{r-j}\tau+b_j}{p^{j}}\right)
    \end{align*}$$
and
$$(T(p)g)(\tau)=p^{k-1}g(p\tau)+\frac{1}{p}\sum_{b=0}^{p-1}g\left(\frac{\tau+b}{p}\right)$$
So we just need to consider the composition $(T(p)T(p^r)f)(\tau)$
In Apostol's book it is said that
$$\begin{align*}
    (T(p)T(p^r)f)(\tau)
    ={}&p^{k-1-r}\sum_{\substack{0\leqslant j\leqslant r\\ 0\leqslant b_j<p^j}}p^{(r-j)k}f\left(\frac{p^{r-j+1}\tau+pb_j}{p^{j}}\right)\\
    &+p^{-1-r}\sum_{\substack{0\leqslant j\leqslant r\\ 0\leqslant b_j<p^j}}\sum_{b=0}^{p-1}f\left(\frac{p^{r-j}\tau+b_j+bp^j}{p^{j+1}}\right)
    \end{align*}$$
**I don't quite understand where that $pb_j$ comes from in the first sum.** It should be $g(p\tau)$ where $g=T(p^r)f$ and thus $g(p\tau)=(T(p^{r})f)(p\tau)$. Shouldn't this be something like
$$(T(p^{r})f)(p\tau)=p^{-r}\sum_{\substack{0\leqslant j\leqslant r\\ 0\leqslant b_j<p^j}}p^{(r-j)k}f\left(\frac{p^{r-j}\boldsymbol{(p\tau)}+b_j}{p^{j}}\right)?$$

---

I tried to read some other materials and found no explanation. In Serre's *A Course in Arithmetic* this is proved by the Fourier expansion of $T_m$. In Gunning's *Lectures on Modular Forms*, this was presented in the same way without explanation. I believe it's a very minor issue but I just couldn't get it. Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.